# Eclipise/Jetty startup exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jetty

For the development of my Java based web application, I am using Eclipse (Oxygen Release 4.7.0), Eclipse Jetty 3.9.0 (plugin), and Java 1.8 (build 144) on a Windows machine.

Each time when I start running the web application within Eclipse on my machine, I get this exception during Jetty startup. Here is the stack:

```
2017-08-09 21:56:11.652:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2017-08-09 21:56:13.621:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 47631
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:744)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.ExtendedAnnotationConfiguration.parse(ExtendedAnnotationConfiguration.java:104)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.ExtendedAnnotationConfiguration.configure(ExtendedAnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1237)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedAdapter.start(JettyEmbeddedAdapter.java:67)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
    at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.embedded.JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.main(JettyEmbeddedLauncherMain.java:42)
2017-08-09 21:56:14.640:INFO:/:No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

I looked everywhere and tried some suggested solutions, but nothing is working.

**Update**

Downloaded Jetty distribution jetty-distribution-9.4.6.v20170531 and installed on my machine. Then pointed the Jetty plugin to using this external version instead of jetty-8.1.14.v20131031, which comes with the launcher. This time, always get this different error at the end of startup:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
```